# How to hide 'Back' button on navigation bar on iPhone?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, navigation, uinavigationcontroller

I added a navigation control to switch between views in my app. But some of the views shouldn't have 'Back' (the previous title) button. Any ideas about how to hide the back button?

Answer (score 834, accepted):

Objective-C:
    `self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;`

Swift:
    `navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true`

Comment: @user8170 how to hide the left barbuttonitem on navigation bar..?

Comment: you cant hide backbutton by `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;`. If you have set leftbarbuttonitem explicitely you can use `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;`. `self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;` will hide Back button Item

Comment: In iOS 7, self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil; does not affect the back button when issued from the viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear, or viewDidAppear.  This line of code does work within the viewdidLoad: self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;

Comment: not sure if this helps but 'self' is always a view controller which is being presented on the top of stack of navigation controller.

Comment: self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES; works for me in viewDidLoad, ios 7

Comment: self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = yes; make issue when I use swipe gesture.which shows the backButton

Comment: this is not working for me. I used this code self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: true)

Answer (score 41):

The best way is to combine these, so it will hide the back button even if you set it up manually :

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=nil;
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton=YES;
```

Comment: To answer user716216, he explained it in his one sentence explanation.  The second line of code is what works for the default case.  The first line of code works if you have created and added the button yourself.

Answer (score 21):

hide back button with bellow code...

```
[self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES animated:YES];
```

**or**

```
[self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES];
```

Also if you have custom `UINavigationBar` then try bellow code

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;
```

Comment: in any class when you used that code then on that class's navigationbar back button will hide ...

Answer (score 6):

In **Swift**:

Add this to the **controller**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: false)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the code:

```
 self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem=nil;
```

Comment: That will show default back bar button item of navigation item.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationitem/1624958-backbarbuttonitem?language=objc

Answer (score 3):

In the function viewDidLoad of the UIViewController use the code:

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget that you need to call it on the object that has the nav controller. For instance, if you have nav controller pushing on a tab bar controller with a RootViewController, calling `self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES` on the RootViewController will do nothing. You would actually have to call `self.tabBarController.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES`

Answer (score 1):

Add this code in your view controller

```
UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 30)];
UIBarButtonItem *btnL = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:myView];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = btnL;
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget that we have the slide to back gesture now. You probably want to remove this as well. **Don't forget to enable it back again if necessary.**

```
if ([self.navigationItem respondsToSelector:@selector(hidesBackButton)]) {
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
}

if ([self.navigationController respondsToSelector:@selector(interactivePopGestureRecognizer)]) {
    self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
}
```

Comment: Without this a lot of controllers without `"back button"` will be swipe-to-back enabled :) Also please note, you will need to enable back the `interactivePopGestureRezognizer` once the user leave the current scene.

Answer (score 1):

For me none of the above seemed to work, It had no visual effect. I am using storyboards with a view that is "embedded" in a navigation controller.

I then at code level add my menuItems and for some reason the "backButton" is visible when visually debugging the view hierarchy, and my menuItem Icon is displayed beneath the invisible "back button".

I tried the settings, as suggested at the various hook methods and that had no effect. Then I tried a more brutal approach and iterate over the subview which also had no effect.

I inspected my icon sizes and appeared to be ok.
After referring to he apple Human Interface Guideline I confirmed my Icons are correct. (1 pixel smaller in my case 24px 48px 72px).

The strangest part then is the actual fix...

**When adding the BarButton Item give it a title with at least one character**, In my case a space character.

Hopes this helps someone.

```
//left menu - the title must have a space
UIBarButtonItem *leftButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@" " <--THE FIX 
                                                                    style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                                  target:self
                                                                  action:@selector(showMenu)];
leftButtonItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_menu"];

[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:leftButtonItem];
```

Answer (score 1):

It wasn't working for me in all cases when I set

self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;

in viewWillAppear or ViewDidLoad, but worked perfectly when I set it in init of the viewController.

Answer (score 0):

try this one - 
`self.navigationController?.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true`

Answer (score 0):

In c# or Xamarin.ios,
this.NavigationItem.HidesBackButton = true;

Answer (score 0):

```
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil
navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
```

if you use this code block inside didLoad or loadView worked but not worked perfectly.İf you look carefully you can see back button is hiding when your view load.Look's weird.

What is the perfect solution?

Add **BarButtonItem** component from componentView *(Command + Shift + L)* to your target viewControllers navigation bar.

Select BarButtonItem set Title = " " from right panel

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: true)
```