# How to hide navigation bar back button

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller

My question is simple, How to hide back button in navigation bar? I see similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/614212/how-to-hide-back-button-on-navigation-bar-on-iphone) in stack overflow but

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
```

not working for me. I am using below code because RootViewController is my Singleton class.

Thanks

i still use both in viewDidLoad but both are not working

```
[RootViewController sharedFirstViewController].navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;

[RootViewController sharedFirstViewController].navigationItem.backBarButtonItem=nil;
```

Comment: hide the button? or the navigation bar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.hidden = YES;` or `self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = nil;`

Place one of these either in `viewWillAppear:`, `viewWillLoad` or `viewDidAppear:` of the class you want to get rid of the back button in.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest doing this before the view appears on the screen. You probably dont want to see the bar and then have it disappear.

So you should call:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
   //Check to see if the Nav har is hidden, and then hide it
   if (!self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.hidden) {
      self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.hidden = YES;
   }
   else { 
      NSLog(@"back button already hidden");
   }
}
```

Note that you can also do this with the whole nav bar completely, if you're trying to free up screen space.

Comment: Property 'hidden' not found on object of type 'UIBarButtonItem ' give in error.