# NavigationItem leftBarButtom item hidden is not working?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationbar

I am displaying ticker View on navigation bar.And do not want to show back button.
To hide back button I wrote the following code:

```
    -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden=false;
    self.navigationController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.tintColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    self.navigationController.navigationItem.hidesBackButton=true;
}
```

in every implementation file.

And applying ticker in app delegate didFinishLaunching method as below.

```
self.navController.navigationItem.hidesBackButton=YES;
[self.navController.navigationBar addSubview:[Constant BSE_Ticker]];
[self.navController.navigationBar addSubview:[Constant NSE_Ticker]];
```

but back button is not hiding.
showing screen shot below

[image: ScreenShot of back button not hiding]

Thanks!
I will appreciate any help.

Comment: Did you try true instead of yes....self.navController.navigationItem.hidesBackButton=true;

Comment: Yeah but both are not working

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/614212/how-to-hide-back-button-on-navigation-bar-on-iphone

Comment: then try Vishal's answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES animated:YES];
```