# Hide back button on iOS 8

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

Here's a fragment of my `Storyboard`:
[image]

As there is a `NavigationController` at the very beginning, a default back button is displayed into each view controller and this is right. But I would like that back button not to be displayed in the `Login` screen show and in the home one. 
So in the `LoginViewController` class I wrote this:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: true)
    ...
}
```

and it works perfectly. I did the same thing into `HomeViewController` class:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: true)
    ...
}
```

but this won't work. In fact here's what I get:

[image]

and so there is a login back button. Why this? 
Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want to just hide the back button? or the entire navigationBar?

Comment: Just the back button if possible... otherwise, if you have a better solution please explain me

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/614212/how-to-hide-back-button-on-navigation-bar-on-iphone

Comment: @iosDev82: thank you for your suggestion. I had already tried all the statements they said but none of them works for me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
self.tabBarController?.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: true)
```

It works in my sample project.

Comment: Ok, this seems to work. Thank you from heart mate. But now I need to understand why...can you explain me please? Where was I making the damned mistake?

Comment: But now I need to understand why...can you explain me please? Where was I making the damned mistake?

Comment: Maybe because that scene is linked to a tab bar controller and it is not a simple view controller like the login scene?

Comment: Yes. This is why you need to access UITabBarController in order to change status UINavigationItem.

Comment: very useful and very kind of yours! :)