# Why does back button not hide in navigation controller?

Tags: ios, swift

**Code:**

```
self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: false)
```

Back button is not getting hidden.

Also tried:

```
self.navigationController!.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: false)
```

in the `viewDidLoad()` method. But it is not working. Why does this not work?

Comment: have you added something on the IB ? before and forgot about removing it ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/614212/how-to-hide-back-button-on-navigation-bar-on-iphone

Comment: You should put this in view will appear. Not view did load.

Comment: Use this methods before you push your controller. It will helps you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, it works for me:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil
self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: false)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is the correct answer, you set the properties on the ViewController's navigationItem and not directly on the NavigationController