# Hide navigation back button on iOS 11.4

Tags: swift, navigation, ios11, back-button, ios11.4

To hide the back button on iOS, we generally write:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.backBarButtonItem = nil
```

or

```
self.navigationController?.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil
```

or

```
self.navigationController?.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = nil
```

or

```
self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: true)
```

None of the above statements works in my case i.e. iOS 11.4.

Is this any known bug in iOS 11.4 version or I am doing anything wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to hide 'Back' button on navigation bar on iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/614212/how-to-hide-back-button-on-navigation-bar-on-iphone)

Answer (score 0):

Try `self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.leftBarButtonItem = nil`

It works for me in iOS 11.4 and iOS 13.1

Answer (score 0):

First make a Outlet like this `@IBOutlet var naviBar: UINavigationItem!`

Then try this `self.naviBar.hidesBackButton = true`

Worked for me...!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 self.navigationController?.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
```